# What almost sure convergence means in the context of strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_sure_convergence#Almost_sure_convergence, a sequence  of random variables $X_n$, which are a function of a shared sample space $Ω$, is said to converge almost surely to $X$ when:

$
    \operatorname{Pr}\Big( \omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \Big) = 1.
  $

The strong law of large numbers says the sample average converges almost surely to the expected value:
$
    \overline{X}_n\ \xrightarrow{a.s.}\ \mu \qquad\textrm{when}\ n \to \infty.
  $

I  am confused as to what this means. For every $n$, $\overline{X}_n$ has a different sample space - the cartesian product corresponding to $n$ i.i.d instances of $X$. How can the definition of almost sure convergence apply here? What is the shared sample space?

---

Comment: The shared sample space is usually taken to be an *infinite* Cartesian product.

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting, I've never seen a sample space definition in this context. Is this definition used in the proof of SLLN?

Comment: Typically not; the statement of the theorem is usually something like "Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are iid...", which presupposes that you already have the shared sample space on which they are defined.  Showing that such a sample space exists is a separate question (if it turned out to be impossible, the SLLN would still be true, but vacuous).

Comment: Note, however, that if you have got all of $X_1, X_2, \dots$ defined on a single sample space, then each $\overline{X}_n$ is defined on that same sample space, just as $\overline{X}_n(\omega) = \frac{1}{n} (X_1(\omega) + \dots + X_n(\omega))$.

Comment: @NateEldredge As the existence of such sample space is non-trivial and crucial for the SLLN result to hold, is this issue discussed somewhere? If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, in order for the SLLN to be non-vacuous, we need to have an appropriate shared sample space where all the $X_n$ are defined.  (Given this, all of the $\overline{X}_n$'s are defined on that same space.)

> **Theorem.** Given any probability distribution function (or Borel probability measure) $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a sequence of measurable functions $X_1, X_2, \dots : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, such that the $X_n$ are iid random variables with common distribution $F$.  Moreover:
>
> - $\Omega$ can be taken to be the countable Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, or equivalently the set of all sequences of real numbers;
> - $\mathcal{F}$ can be taken to be the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is generated by all "cylinder sets" of the form $A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, where $n$ is any integer and $A_1, \dots, A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ are Borel;
> - $X_n$ can be taken to be the coordinate function $X_n(x_1, x_2, \dots) = x_n$.

The measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is sometimes called "infinite product measure".  It can be constructed directly using the Caratheodory extension theorem, but is usually treated instead as a special case of the more general **Kolmogorov extension theorem**, which allows for dependence between the $X_i$.  The Kolmogorov extension theorem is treated in most measure theory texts, such as for instance [these notes by Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/245a-notes-6-outer-measures-pre-measures-and-product-measures/#more-4371).